# How can I save TKinter PhotoImage to .GIF?

Tags: python, tkinter

Can I save a tkinter PhotoImage as .gif (or any other image extension) using only Python and tkinter?

Comment: If you have a PhotoImage created like `photo = PhotoImage(file="image.gif")`, then the image already exists on your hard drive as `image.gif`. No saving required.

Comment: I create PhotoImage without specifying an image, i fill it myself.

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't know you could do that :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `photo` is the variable holding your image, you should be able to just say:

```
photo.write('some_name.gif', format='gif')
```

Although it doesn't say explicitly, [it supports viewing PGM, PPM, GIF, PNG formats](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c43714fbcdb9bb0927872d6ebf5697edd2e2a1e9/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L4123), so I assume it can save to these formats as well.

Comment: .png format works as well. There are problems with transparency, thouhgh:(

Comment: Good to know.  I actually tried & failed with `.png`, but likely had an issue elsewhere.

Comment: You might have written it like '.png' instead of 'png'.

Comment: Nothing about it on help() :(

Comment: What I'm needing is the transparency from a png, but I can't find any help in this area. I'm loading a png image as PhotoImage, and then turning around and saving the same image as a different file. The resulting image seems to skip whole lines and invert the transparency on other lines.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the method `write` can be used to save a PhotoImage to a file.

```
>>> help(Tkinter.PhotoImage.write)
Help on method write in module Tkinter:

write(self, filename, format=None, from_coords=None) unbound Tkinter.PhotoImage method
    Write image to file FILENAME in FORMAT starting from
    position FROM_COORDS.
```

Sample usage would be something like:

```
my_photo_image.write("output.gif")
```