# Python animated gif without ImageMagick

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm trying to make an animated gif in Python. I've found lots of resources; it seems like the suggested method is to use the `matplotlib.animation` package. This method requires ImageMagick to be installed and configured.

I don't necessarily have a problem with this, but I'm teaching a class and I would like to know if there is a "built-in" way to create gifs. By built-in I mean not using any external software or non-standard modules (and available in Python 2 and 3). I'm willing to sacrifice creation speed and quality of the animation. Something akin to Matlab's [imwrite](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) would be ideal. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Unless you absolutely need a GIF, you could probably put an animation together in tkinter.

Comment: Potentially useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387745/how-can-i-save-tkinter-photoimage-to-gif

Comment: I think ImageMagick is pretty standard; I wonder how you could expect your students to be able to install python, numpy and matplotlib but not to install ImageMagick.

Comment: If you teach CS, you may be interested in the new [CS Educator's Stack Exchange](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/) (though since it's still in private beta, for now, it's easiest to enter through [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92460))